# what is the impact of small hive tables?

Tags: hive

In one of my usecases, several tables were created out of a bunch of csv files. Each csv file was about 50-80MB.Table is configured to contain 2 buckets. Tables are stored in ORC format. However, when I see in hive warehouse directory in hdfs, it is only about 4 MB - 5MB. I have already brought down the hive block size from its default to 64MB. My concern here is that small files in hdfs put pressure on Namenode. Similarly, is it an issue with small hive tables? Can I still bring down size of hive block?

Comment: About HDFS block size: it is just an **indication** that large files should be split in *logical* blocks, for better parallelization of future MapReduce read operations. It makes absolutely no difference in physical disk usage when writing.

Comment: About small files: sure, a very large number of files (and/or a very large number of blocks, if these files are large enough to be split) will consume a large quantity of RAM on the NameNode. But it will also have a strong impact on performance for Hive queries that scan all files in a specific directory (time lost scanning the directory, time lost scanning each file -- and worse, lots of time lost allocating one Mapper container for each file, if you don't activate `combineinputformat`)

Comment: Repeating: it's the number of file entries that consumes RAM in the NameNode, not their size, and certainly not the default block size *(unless you force a very low value e.g. 64 KB - please leave the default value as it was and stop trying silly things without reading the docs)*